# How to add red fives to a riichi set?

Tags: riichi-mahjong

when using the rule for adding the three red fives in riichi mahjong, does one *add* the fives to the set, or do they *replace* fives already in the set with the red fives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replace them, because otherwise we will end up with five copies of the 5-numbered tiles, which is not the intention of using red fives.